# auto-close JMenu when cursor goes outside

Tags: java, swing, menu, awt, listener

I have a problem with auto hiding `JMenu`. I don't know how it's name but screenshot should explain everything.

[image]

When cursor moves on `JMenu`, it's unfolding and I can select any `JMenuItem`, when cursor goes to another `JMenu`, previous is closed and new is open. But I have no idea which event (or events) I should use to detect when cursor goes out of `JMenuItem` and NOT goes to any else.

Here is my code:

```
    public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JMenuBar menuBar=new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu Menu1=new JMenu("Menu1"); //empty
    private JMenu Menu2=new JMenu("Menu2");
    private JMenu Menu3=new JMenu("Menu3");
    private JMenu Menu4=new JMenu("Menu4"); //empty
    private JMenu Menu5=new JMenu("Menu5"); //empty

    private JMenuItem Menu2Item1=new JMenuItem("MenuItem1");
    private JMenuItem Menu2Item2=new JMenuItem("MenuItem2");
    private JMenuItem Menu2Item3=new JMenuItem("MenuItem3");
    private JMenuItem Menu2Item4=new JMenuItem("MenuItem4");

    private JMenuItem Menu3Item1=new JMenuItem("MenuItem1");
    private JMenuItem Menu3Item2=new JMenuItem("MenuItem2");
    private JMenuItem Menu3Item3=new JMenuItem("MenuItem3");
    private JMenuItem Menu3Item4=new JMenuItem("MenuItem4");
    private JMenuItem Menu3Item5=new JMenuItem("MenuItem5");
    private JMenuItem Menu3Item6=new JMenuItem("MenuItem6");
    private JMenuItem Menu3Item7=new JMenuItem("MenuItem7");

    private MouseAdapter menuAutoFocusAdapter=new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent menuEnter) {
            ((JMenu) menuEnter.getSource()).doClick();
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent menuExit) {
            if (((JMenu) menuExit.getSource()).getItemCount()==0) {
                MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().clearSelectedPath();
            }
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent menuClick) {
            ((JMenu) menuClick.getSource()).doClick();
        }
    };

    public MainWindow() {
        super("AutoHide Menu");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800, 600);
        setVisible(true);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(Menu1);
        menuBar.add(Menu2);
        menuBar.add(Menu3);
        menuBar.add(Menu4);
        menuBar.add(Menu5);

        Menu2.add(MenuItem1);
        Menu2.add(MenuItem2);
        Menu2.add(MenuItem3);
        Menu2.add(MenuItem4);

        Menu3.add(MenuItem1);
        Menu3.add(MenuItem2);
        Menu3.add(MenuItem3);
        Menu3.add(MenuItem4);
        Menu3.add(MenuItem5);
        Menu3.add(MenuItem6);
        Menu3.add(MenuItem7);

        Menu1.addMouseListener(menuAutoFocusAdapter);
        Menu2.addMouseListener(menuAutoFocusAdapter);
        Menu3.addMouseListener(menuAutoFocusAdapter);
        Menu4.addMouseListener(menuAutoFocusAdapter);
        Menu5.addMouseListener(menuAutoFocusAdapter);
    }
}
```

If `JMenu` hasn't any `JMenuItem` all works good but if `JMenu` is not empty I cannot use `mouseExited(MouseEvent menuExit)` from `MouseAdapter` and this function `MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().clearSelectedPath()` because it closes `JMenu` everytime.
Any ideas?

Comment: *"I have a problem with auto hiding `JMenu`."*  As a user I have a problem with them too.  They are bloody irritating.

Comment: Agreed - most users will be extremely annoyed if the submenu collapses just because the mouse happens to stray outside one of the menu items while they are trying to navigate up or down, or in/out of a cascaded submenu.

Comment: why would the menu count be 0?

Comment: For example when you need to have menu with simple Home button :) I need to use getItemCount()==0 because for JMenu, isEmpty() not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think, I found solution. This is one extra `Adapter` which catches `MouseMotion` on specific controls.

```
private MouseMotionAdapter menuLostFocusAdapter=new MouseMotionAdapter() {
     public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent mouseMoveOutside) {
          if (weaponsTypes.getSelectionModel().isSelected()) {
               MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().clearSelectedPath();
               weaponsTypes.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
          }
     }
};
```

I'm using to it `addMouseMotionListener(menuLostFocusAdapter)` for all controls which are under my `JMenu`. I know it's not fast and beauty but it works quiet well.